# Applying chrome 36 patch on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1

I can see the SDL has released patch to fix issues in Chrome 36 for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 version.

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

Can I directly install this patch on version SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can verify that you can apply this patch to the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 as we have applied it and it is working without any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to apply this patch to 2011 SP1 version. can you confirm if that is fine.In answer you mentioned about HR1 but I am applying this to 2011 SP1 version.

Comment: It would work without any issue. I would recommend you take backup before you make any file replacement. I have done for 2011 SP1 as well and it works there too.

Comment: Thank you. I have applied for 2011 SP1. It is working fine without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Its just one XML file Change, you can compare both XMLs & give it a try (if you can not upgrade now), But Its strongly recommended to upgrade to HR2, as it will help you in future patches as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I can see that its just one xml change. Actually to install HR2 patch we need to upgrade content delivery as well which is time consuming. so thinking if we can directly apply this patch on 2011 SP1 version directly. Can you suggest me if I am doing correctly or not.

Comment: I just compared both xmls. I think there are some 8 changes related to reading xml nodes. I can give a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: so when i compare between HR2 and the patch i see following changes...... Tridion.Utils.Xml.createAttributeNS = function Tridion$Xml$createAttributeNS(xmlDoc, ns, name)
 this method is totally updated except first three lines,..... other change 2) In following method else block is totally updated except return statement.  Tridion.Utils.Xml.getOuterXml = function Tridion$Xml$getOuterXml(node, xpath)

Comment: I have applied it and it works. Thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 4):

There is some hope that the issue may not be present in Chrome 38. If you look at Chrome's bug tracker, you'll see a note to this effect.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390879

However - please note that the issue is still officially "Unconfirmed", so any fix would be "by accident" rather than as a result of someone actively fixing the problem.

So - it might be worth considering whether you need to patch at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you contact support there is a patch available for SP1 HR1 now as well. However, the others' answers still apply.